# Element with only class name and repeats multiple times on the page. Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have an element which has only class name as it’s locator or property which can be used for it to locate. I have tried multiple different solution but it doesn’t click on the right one or doesn’t do anything at all. I have tried using X-path but that doesn’t help either because it’s not reliable.

```
  <a class=“Icon-shadows”
    <i class=“fa fas.fw fa-info”
  ::before 
  I>
  a>
```

This information button appears more then 25-40 times on a page if you click on it you get information about The content. 
I can add some more information if need be. Any help suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please share your x-path which you have tried and the parent elment html code. Do you want to click any one of info element or any specific element?.

Comment: How do yo go to new line  in comments to separate the code? I keep trying and instead of going to new line it keeps posting. But I have tried the using class names, Tag names and copying the xpath from the source code. 'findelement(By.calssname(fa-info)'

Comment: FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='app-main']/div/div/div[2]/section/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]")).Click();

Comment: I want to click on the specific ones

Comment: The html code is too long to put in one i will put in two different comments

Comment: <li class="p-2 hooper-slide is-active is-current" style="width: 661px;">
      <div class="account-slide relative ratio-4:3 lg:ratio-2:1 rounded overflow-hidden">
        <img src="it's the same image src for all of them" class="object-cover absolute inset-0 w-full h-full">
            <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 py-1 px-2 flex flex-col text-white text-2xl block">
                  <!----> 
                      <a class="icon-shadow">
                             <i class="fas fa-fw fa-info text-yellow-500">
                     </i>
               </a>
         </div>

Comment: '<div class="info-overlay animated fast bg-overlay-85 absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 flex items-start leading-tight text-white pt-2 px-2 pb-2 cursor-pointer">
              <div class="flex-1 min-w-0">
           <h3 class="text-xl font-medium truncate">name 1L</h3>
        <div class="leading-tight mt-1"><div class="hidden md:block">2nd line name</div> 
       <div>3rd nam</div></div> <!----></div> <div><a href="/account/000" class="block text-2xl"><i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-fw">
          </i>
           </a>
        </div>
            </div>
      </div>
        </li>'

Comment: I tried to put 4 spaces and '' but it wouldnt show as code sorry. I would hope someone helps instead of just coming and giving the negative

Comment: You can add/update to the question itself if it is too long.

Comment: get the most reliable and stable element closest to the element you want to perform an action on and create XPath using its id with the help of xpath features like Following, Ancestor, parent, sibling etc. whichever applicable for your case.

Comment: try to use the code mode when you are pasting code. It will be easier to see. Just copy paste the whole html as code.

Comment: I will change it

Comment: Thanks for letting me know how to do it better I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try saving them to a list, and click on the specific one you need

```
IList<IWebElement> infoBtn = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a[class='Icon-shadows']"));
infoBtn[4].Click();
```

Comment: when i use the above statement i get an error that the index is out of the order

Comment: Do you used "FindElements" Method or just FindElement ?